# How to run a sparQL query?

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform, rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I discovered the SparQL syntax at the Mozilla Festival 12.

The demonstrator was using a proprietary web-based interface and I was wondering if there is open services or maybe **(cross-platform) GUI application** ? In order to :

1. write your query ;
2. execute the query ;
3. explore the results.

Some kind of SparQL IDE.

Comment: AFAIK, [Vusualbox](http://alangrafu.github.io/visualbox/) was used at the Mozilla Festival 12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I found :

#### Cross-Platform (Linux/Windows/Mac?)

- [Twinkle](http://www.ldodds.com/projects/twinkle/) (Java)
- [sparql-aderis](http://code.google.com/p/sparql-aderis/) (Java) :

  - provide [CLI interface](http://code.google.com/p/sparql-aderis/wiki/Getting_Started#Command-line_execution) ;
  - last build 2010.

#### Windows-only

- [SparqlGUI](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/releases) (requires .NET; installed as part of the dotNetRDF tools installer) ;

Answer (score 3):

Five years later, another GUI client is [YASGUI](http://yasgui.org).

There is also a very elaborate client with text and GUI interfaces for query writing and result/data exploration called [Gruff](https://franz.com/agraph/gruff/) but I do not know if it's only for the same company's triple store (AllegroGraph) or if it can also connect to a generic SPARQL endpoint.

Comment: Both of these are very useful tools recommended for newcomers to at least look at before they begin learning.

Answer (score 2):

a few links, you choose.

- TopBraid Composer Free Edition is a professional development environment for the W3C's Semantic Web standards RDF Schema, the OWL Web Ontology Language and the SPARQL Query Language.
- Twinkle is a simple GUI interface that wraps the ARQ SPARQL query engine. The tool should be useful both for people wanting to learn the SPARQL query language, as well as those doing Semantic Web development.
- Corese is a Semantic Web Factory implementing W3C RDF, RDFS, SPARQL 1.1 Query & Update, SPARQL Rules for RDF. It and comes with a GUI also
- Semantic Web Import is a plugin allowing the Gephi platform to visualize the semantic RDF graphs using Sparql queries
- Sgvizler is a javascript which renders the result of SPARQL SELECT queries into charts or html elements.

And of course, some RDF datastores provide a Sparql endpoint, for instance [dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and [its french version](http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql). You can access them directly on the web page, or programatically

Have fun !

Answer (score 1):

An interesting cross platform solution if you are happy to use a web-based GUI is the [Flint SPARQL Editor](http://openup.tso.co.uk/blog/flint-sparql-editor) which comes out of the UK government labs and uses the popular CodeMirror Javascript library under the hood

Their original version only supported SPARQL 1.0 and I'm not sure if they ever updated it to SPARQL 1.1, I know this is possible because we've done in for a product our company builds.

Answer (score 1):

Online UI are http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ and http://dbpedia.org/sparql/ , they both accept SparQL queries. I noticed http://querybuilder.dbpedia.org/ its use is to explore.